# Documentation for SKEW.P

Tags: excel

Original question is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1658801).

I think the formula for population skewness from photo [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/skew-p-function-76530a5c-99b9-48a1-8392-26632d542fcb) is wrong.

I think correct formula is [this](https://ibb.co/mCvrv2q).

Am i right?

[EDIT]

1. Please check the example and the result in documentation with both formulas.

Comment: The formula in Excel's documentation is neither a formula for skewness nor is it what Excel actually does. It is just a typographical error in the documentation (this is obvious from the fact that there is a dashed-line square in the formula, which is a graphical placeholder for a term in Microsoft's equation editor and means nothing).

Comment: @ChrisHaug That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the formula in Excel's documentation is not really a valid formula for anything: there is a dashed-line square in there, which is a graphical placeholder for a term in Microsoft's equation editor and means nothing.

If you simply ignore it, you do not get a valid formula for skewness. The quickest way to see this is that the result is not scale-free (skewness is a "standardized" measure).

Fortunately, the formula in the documentation is not what Excel actually does, it is just a typographical error in the documentation. You can figure this out by taking a small dataset and computing it by hand with either formula and comparing to SKEW.P's result. I haven't tested it extensively, but it appears to be applying the other formula that you've shown, and it definitely does not use the one in the documentation.